# Fetch data for record edit page

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a page that lets you edit user data. I'm using `FlowRouter` for the routing and it can be found on the route `/employees/:id`.

I need to update the detail form when data changes on the server and leave the route if it was deleted by other client.

I decided to use `Tracker.autorun` which informs me whenever the data changes. The previous user info is stored on the template so it's easy to tell if the record was deleted.

```
Template.UpdateEmployee.onCreated(function () {
    const self = this;
    self.subscribe('user', FlowRouter.getParam('id'));

    self.autorun(function () {
        const _id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        const user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id});

        if(!user && self.user)
            FlowRouter.go('/employees');
        self.user = user;

        if(!user)
            return;
        user.email = user.emails[0].address;
        $('.ui.form').form('set values',user);
    });

});
```

And lastly in the `onRendered` callback I'm checking if the data was set on template as I believe not doing so could lead to data being available before the template is rendered and hence values wouldn't get set properly. Is this correct?

```
Template.UpdateEmployee.onRendered(function () {
    if(this.user){
        user.email = user.emails[0].address;
        $('.ui.form').form('set values',user);
    }
});
```

Are there any pitfalls to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple drawbacks inherently. The first one is doing a find query on the client. Typically you would want to return data from the server using Meteor publish and subscribe.

The second is you are passing the key to find the data over the URL. This can be spoofed by other users for them to find that users data.

Lastly if you are doing a find on the user object, I assume you might be storing data there. This is generally bad practice. If you need to store user data with their profile, it's best to create a new collection and publish/subscribe what you need.

Comment: As you can see in the code provided I'm indeed subscribing and only one record will be returned by the server, but I still need to get the object, which just made me realised I didn't need to provide the id to find one as no other users will be available.

Comment: Secondly it's administrator updating employees' info. And to your third point, I did read the docs and browsed  SO  and from what I've found profile is modifiable by the user, which I don't want and in this case either deny rules or storing data on the user object should be both fine. Excuse double comment, on phone

Comment: Oops didn't see the subscription method. Then overall I'd still say you're fine. I'd personally though seperate my data from the user profile and keep the user id in a session rather than pass it over the wire.